# file uploading via ajax

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework, image-upload

Here, i am uploading an image via ajax in scala. After successful uploading, i want to show the image instantly on the html page. But after uploading the image is not being shown. The image id is correct!

```
$('#'+frm).ajaxSubmit({
  target: '#output',
  success:  function(message){
    var result=JSON.parse(message);

    if(result["result"]==1) { //indicating success        
      if(frm == 'profileForm') {
        document.getElementById('profileImage').src = "/assets/images/profile/@(session("userId")).jpg";
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is being shown?  What is the request being made and what is the server's response?

Comment: request is made via post, response is {"result":"1"} and i want the new image to be shown

Comment: What about the request for the image?  What does the `src` value become, and what is the request/response for that image?

Comment: `@(session("userId"))` might be handle server side no ?

Comment: @Koryonik: That might not be a problem here, though.  If the user ID is known when the page is loaded and doesn't change then it can be used to pre-populate this value under the assumption that the uploaded file will match it.

Comment: As well, Ok. and you can access to image directly from generated URL ""/assets/images/profile/@(session("userId")).jpg" ?

Comment: @David src is the attribute of input element of image type here.

Comment: actually, the image is saved with name similar as of the userId(that is in session). And at backend i change the image but still the path will remain the same of image(since, it is stored with the userId ). So, here, somehow i have to refresh that particular image control so that the new image could be fetched. how??

Comment: @user2155922: You haven't really answered the question.  What does the runtime value of the `src` attribute become?  Does it make a new request for the image?  What is the server's response to that request?  You have to debug this, I can't do it for you.